# Sort names based on last name within excel and paste in 3-column table in a newly generated word document

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an excel document where I want to copy over the names that have been "checked" via a checkbox, alphabetize on the last names and copy over these alphabetized names to a newly generated word document and paste them in a 3 column table. The number of rows is dynamic, based on the number of checkboxes the user has checked. Here is the code I currently have:

```
    Dim cl As Range, txt As String, temp1 as Variant, temp2 as String
    
    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D6:D122")
        If cl Then 
           temp1 = VBA.Split(cl.offset(0,-2), " ") ' the names are a couple columns before the corresponding checkbox
           temp2 = temp1(1) & ", " & temp1(0) 
           txt = txt & vbLf & temp2
        End If
    Next cl
    
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then    ' show Word if you have something to output
        Dim wdApp As New Word.Application   ' declare and create object at once
        With wdApp
            .Documents.Add  ' the added document automatically becomes active
            .Selection.TypeText Mid(txt, 2)   'remove extra (lead) vbLf and output text to Word
            .ActiveDocument.Range.Sort
            .Visible = True 'show Word after processing to improve performance
        End With
   
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that I don't want to paste "last name, first name" in the word document, I want to paste "first name last name" which has been sorted by the last name in a word table with dynamic/undefined number of rows.

Comment: After you sort it, assign a string variable to `ActiveDocument.Range.Text` then use Split the names back to array and rearrange the order? Once it's reordered, paste it back into the document.

Or, can't you just sort it on Excel based on the last name?

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondWu. I do not want to make any changes to the actual excel document, which is why I need to perform all actions in the VBA script.

Comment: Make a helper sheet, transfer whatever you need then delete it later?

Comment: That could be a solution, but was wondering if there was a way to do it without creating a helper sheet, just via the VBA code. I also need to copy over the sorted names in a dynamic table within the word doc..

Comment: Look for a quick sort function and sort it in vba? Theres plenty of sample

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the names first using an array. The example below is based on a range with lastname in the first column and firstname in the second. Depending on your needs you might have to tweak it a bit, but the principle should still work.

```
Sub RangeToArr()
Dim wApp As New Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Document, wTbl As Table
Dim i As Long, Arr As Variant

    Arr = Sheet1.Range("A2:B7").Value
    Arr = SortArr(Arr)

    ''create document
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add


    ''create table
    With wDoc                     
        Set wTbl = .Tables.Add(.Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.Count).Range, UBound(Arr), 3)  
    End With

    ''fill names into table
    With wTbl
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            .cell(i, 1).Range.InsertAfter Arr(i, 2) & " " & Arr(i, 1) ''names to column 1
             '' .cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter ''Optional input column 2
             '' .cell(i, 3).Range.InsertAfter ''Optional input column 3
        Next i
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    wApp.Visible = True ''show Word

End Sub
```

This is the sort function:

```
Function SortArr(Arr As Variant)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp1, Temp2

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If UCase(Arr(i, 1)) > UCase(Arr(j, 1)) Then
            Temp1 = Arr(j, 1)
            Temp2 = Arr(j, 2)
            Arr(j, 1) = Arr(i, 1)
            Arr(j, 2) = Arr(i, 2)
            Arr(i, 1) = Temp1
            Arr(i, 2) = Temp2
        End If
    Next j
Next i

SortArr = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answers my question and solves my problem

Comment: This function sorts the first+last name combos based on last name within vba. Is that not what you needed? You'd just have to work part of the first block of code into your own set-up, or is it unclear how you would do that?

Comment: I understand that it sorts, but my problem also involves pasting it into a word table with a dynamic number of rows, which is also present in my question title

Comment: My bad, I did overlook that part of the question. I've updated my answer with code to create a table and insert the names into it. Does that help?

Comment: Yes! I'll try it out and get back here!

Comment: I could not figure out adding the "checked" names into the array. Could you explain how I could do that?

Comment: @Sonali Which part are you stuck at? What do you mean by "checked" names?

Comment: @SonaliJ I can't tell exactly how you're reading from the checkboxes.. are you using the 'If cl Then' part for that? And are those form checkboxes, or ActiveX? Once I know this I could try to plug it into your posted code.